# Cannot understand how jCuda cuLaunchKernel work?

Tags: jcuda

I am trying to understand how to use Cuda in Java. I am using jCuda.

Everything was fine until I came across an example containing the code:

```
    // Set up the kernel parameters: A pointer to an array
    // of pointers which point to the actual values.
    Pointer kernelParameters = Pointer.to(
        Pointer.to(new int[]{numElements}),
        Pointer.to(deviceInputA),
        Pointer.to(deviceInputB),
        Pointer.to(deviceOutput)
    );
```

The kernel function prototype is:

```
__global__ void add(int n, float *a, float *b, float *sum)
```

**The question is:**
In terms of c, does it not seem that we are passing something like?

```
(***n, ***a, ***b, ***sum)
```

So basically, do we always have to have:

```
Pointer kernelParameters = Pointer.to( double pointer, double pointer, ...)???
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`cuLaunchKernel` function of JCuda](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/driver/JCudaDriver.html#cuLaunchKernel%28jcuda.driver.CUfunction,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20jcuda.driver.CUstream,%20jcuda.Pointer,%20jcuda.Pointer%29) corresponds to the [`cuLaunchKernel` function of CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gb8f3dc3031b40da29d5f9a7139e52e15). The signature of this function in CUDA is

```
CUresult cuLaunchKernel(
    CUfunction f, 
    unsigned int gridDimX, 
    unsigned int gridDimY, 
    unsigned int gridDimZ, 
    unsigned int blockDimX, 
    unsigned int blockDimY, 
    unsigned int blockDimZ, 
    unsigned int sharedMemBytes, 
    CUstream hStream, 
    void** kernelParams, 
    void** extra)
```

where the `kernelParams` is the only parameter that is relevant for this question. The documentation says

> Kernel parameters can be specified via `kernelParams`. If `f` has N parameters, then `kernelParams` needs to be an array of N pointers. Each of `kernelParams[0]` through `kernelParams[N-1]` must point to a region of memory from which the actual kernel parameter will be copied.

---

The key point here is the last sentence: The elements of the `kernelParams` array **are** not the actual kernel parameters. They only **point** to the actual kernel parameters.

And indeed, this has the odd effect that for a kernel that receives a single `float *pointer`, you could basically set up the kernel parameters as follows:

```
float *pointer= allocateSomeDeviceMemory();
float** pointerToPointer = &pointer;
float*** pointerToPointerToPointer = &pointerToPointer;
void **kernelParams = pointerToPointerToPointer;
```

<sub>(This is just to make clear that this is indeed a pointer to a pointer to a pointer - in reality, wou wouldn't write it like that)</sub>

---

Now, the "structure" of the kernel parameters is basically the same for JCuda and for CUDA. Of course you can not take "the address of a pointer" in Java, but the number of indirections is the same. Imagine you have a kernel like this:

```
__global__ void example(int value, float *pointer)
```

In the CUDA C API, you can then define the kernel parameters as follows:

```
int value = 123;
float *pointer= allocateSomeDeviceMemory();

int* pointerToValue = &value;
float** pointerToPointer = &pointer;

void **kernelParams = {
    pointerToValue,
    pointerToPointer
};
```

The setup is done analogously in the JCuda Java API:

```
int value = 123;
Pointer pointer= allocateSomeDeviceMemory();

Pointer pointerToValue = Pointer.to(new int[]{value});
float** pointerToPointer = Pointer.to(pointer);

Pointer kernelParameters = Pointer.to(
    pointerToValue,
    pointerToPointer
);
```

The main difference that is relevant here is that you can write this a bit more concisely in C, using the address operator `&`:

```
void **kernelParams = {
    &value,             // This can be imagined as a pointer to an int
    &pointer            // This can be imagined as a pointer to a pointer
};
```

But this is basically the same as in the example that you provided:

```
Pointer kernelParameters = Pointer.to(
    Pointer.to(new int[]{value}),   // A pointer to an int
    Pointer.to(pointer)             // A pointer to a pointer
);
```

---

Again, the key point is that with something like

```
void **kernelParams = {
    &value,
};
```

or

```
Pointer kernelParameters = Pointer.to(
    Pointer.to(new int[]{value}),
);
```

you are not passing the `value` to the kernel directly. Instead, you are telling CUDA: "Here is an array of pointers. The first pointer points to an `int` value. Copy the value from this memory location, and use it as the actual value for the kernel call".

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation!